# adding logbook xml to spring boot project makes this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, logback

I just added logbook.xml to the resources folder, and then I am getting this error:

```
 WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration#webMvcTagsProvider matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcTagsProvider; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   
  

   ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.elasticsearch.client.Client' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.unboundid.ldap.listener.InMemoryDirectoryServer' (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)


   MappingsEndpointAutoConfiguration.ReactiveWebConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler' (OnClassCondition)

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - ResourceBundle did not find bundle with basename messages (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)

   MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no property management.endpoint.metrics.enabled found so using endpoint default; @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no 'management.endpoints' property marked it as exposed (OnAvailableEndpointCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MustacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession' (OnClassCondition)

   NewRelicMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.newrelic.NewRelicMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   NoOpMeterRegistryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry' simpleMeterRegistry (OnBeanCondition)

   OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.JwtConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken', 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration.OpaqueTokenConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.BearerTokenAuthenticationToken', 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector' (OnClassCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' (OnClassCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#buildProperties:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}' (OnResourceCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#gitProperties:
      Did not match:
         - GitResource did not find git info at classpath:git.properties (ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.GitResourceAvailableCondition)

   PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   QuartzAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.quartz.Scheduler' (OnClassCondition)

   RSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.rsocket.RSocketFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RSocketRequesterAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.rsocket.RSocketFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RSocketSecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.rsocket.core.SecuritySocketAcceptorInterceptor' (OnClassCondition)

   RSocketServerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.rsocket.RSocketFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RSocketStrategiesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator' (OnClassCondition)

   RabbitAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.rabbitmq.client.Channel' (OnClassCondition)

   RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   RabbitMetricsAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveCloudFoundryActuatorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ReactiveElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.ReactiveElasticsearchClient' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveHealthEndpointConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveManagementContextAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveRestClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   RedisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories' (OnClassCondition)

   RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   RestClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient' (OnClassCondition)

   Saml2RelyingPartyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   ScheduledTasksEndpointAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no property management.endpoint.scheduledtasks.enabled found so using endpoint default; @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no 'management.endpoints' property marked it as exposed (OnAvailableEndpointCondition)

   SecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityRequestMatchersManagementContextConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher' (OnClassCondition)

   SendGridAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.sendgrid.SendGrid' (OnClassCondition)

   ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.JerseyServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig' (OnClassCondition)

   ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration.ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (management.server.add-application-context-header=true) did not find property 'add-application-context-header' (OnPropertyCondition)

   ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration#forwardedHeaderFilter:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (server.forward-headers-strategy=framework) did not find property 'server.forward-headers-strategy' (OnPropertyCondition)

   ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server', 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader', 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext' (OnClassCondition)

   ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration.EmbeddedUndertow:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'io.undertow.Undertow', 'org.xnio.SslClientAuthMode' (OnClassCondition)

   SessionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.session.Session' (OnClassCondition)

   SessionsEndpointAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   ShutdownEndpointAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no property management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled found so using endpoint default (OnAvailableEndpointCondition)

   SignalFxMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.signalfx.SignalFxMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrHealthContributorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.application.admin.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   StatsdMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.statsd.StatsdMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration#taskScheduler:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (names: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor; ; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans named org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor (OnBeanCondition)

   ThreadDumpEndpointAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no property management.endpoint.threaddump.enabled found so using endpoint default; @ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint no 'management.endpoints' property marked it as exposed (OnAvailableEndpointCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   WavefrontMetricsExportAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.micrometer.wavefront.WavefrontMeterRegistry' (OnClassCondition)

   WebClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   WebClientMetricsConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxEndpointManagementContextConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxMetricsAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.ResourceChainCustomizerConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain did not find class org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator (OnEnabledResourceChainCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver' beanNameViewResolver (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#localeResolver:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.locale) did not find property 'locale' (OnPropertyCondition)

   WebServiceTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.JettyWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.info.InfoContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.health.HealthContributorAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.mappings.MappingsEndpointAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.EndpointAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration



23:29:06.926 [main] INFO  o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
23:29:06.946 [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
```

and if I check the dependency tree, I get:

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.28:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO]    \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
```

Comment: I don't see any error here?

Comment: As Darren pointed out the messages you saw are just debug message of spring boot autoconfiguration. There is no error regarding your application. Most likely you have debug parameter set as true. That is why you see this report.